# compiling c++ opencv 3.1 on raspberry pi 3

Tags: c++, opencv, shared-libraries

I followed

http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/

and I see that the opencv shared libraries are inside /usr/local/lib, however when I try to compile my c++ code I get the following errors

"no such directory"

and

"Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found"

I think the problem is because I have the libraries installed locally. What file would I have to edit to make the compiler look at /usr/local/include instead of only /usr/include?

Comment: If you are getting "no such directory" then the path is wrong. Try fixing the path first and see if that fixes the 2nd problem.

Comment: On my jetson tk1 I installed opencv normally and not locally and doing #include "opencv2/core/core.hpp" worked fine :/